# Can AWS Glue catalog point to a data location in Azure ADLS?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-databricks, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-databricks

We are trying configure AWS Databricks Runtime to use the AWS Glue Data Catalog as its metastore. In this environment ,Azure ADLS is one of the source system.In that case,Can AWS Glue catalog point to a data location in Azure ADLS?

Answer (score 0):

AWS glue catalog can speak JDBC, so if you can configure Azure ADLS to speak JDBC, which it seems like you can, you should be able to do this.

[glue catalog documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/populate-data-catalog.html)